# asp.net context An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I´m facing a problem when I try to run the following line:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private EspEntities _context = new EspEntities();
}
```

I get a message:

> An item with the same key has already been added.

I've tried to replace the Edmx file, but I can´t figure out why this is happening. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Do you have a dictionary somewhere? Is there code for what is in the class EspEntities()?

Comment: Agreed, sounds like you are adding to a dictionary somewhere with a duplicate key.

Comment: Apparently the constructor of EspEntities does something that includes a Key. Without showing this constructor and all functions it calls we don't know what happens.